# Is the example of measuring area in openlayers wrong?

Tags: openlayers

I calculated the area of ​​the polygon from the URL below through an example.

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure.html

[measure test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s02Wz.jpg)

However, as shown in the measurement test picture, the measurement seems to be wrong.

The areas of small triangles and large polygons are calculated similarly.

What is the problem?

Am I mistaken?

Comment: It is not working as expected as you have drawn a kinked polygon.  You would need a apply a third party utility such as https://turfjs.org/docs/#unkinkPolygon  before calculating the area.

Comment: Thank you. How to distincguish if the polygon I drew is a unkinked polygon?

Comment: If you may be drawing kinked polygons it may be simpler to pass them all through turf https://codesandbox.io/s/measure-forked-h47g3